# Get time value from html input of datetimepicker

Tags: php, html

I've using the datetime_picker available on the internet to create a value for the html text input. Now the problem is how can I separate the value as plainly date and plainly time value. Using the date_picker, I could get an TEXT input as follow,

2013/12/29 12:52

It is possible to insert this value into date and time column separately in my database. If can, how the coding should look like, usually I get the html text input using the code like

```
$id = pg_escape_string($_POST['ID']);
```

But this will get the whole value. I hope to get a more detailed coding as I just started to learn the html and php, thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Are you asking how to split or how to store in db?

Comment: Use `date('Y:m:d',$date)` function.

Comment: @Anthony How to split it in order to store in DB..because if I use $date = pg_escape_string($_POST['datetime']); it works fine for me to get date, but I dono how to get the time at behind

Comment: What does `var_dump($date)` return ?

Comment: It's honestly very unclear what you're goal is or the underlying problem. Is the problem that you want to store the date and time separately, or that when you try to insert the datetime string to the database it's only saving the date? Do you need to know how to create the columns in the database, or how to parse the string so that the date value and time value can be stored as two distinct variables? There are a variety of answers/solutions depending on what you actually are trying to do and the obstacles in the way. Would you store the date and time as one value in the db if you could?

Comment: @Anthony I already have a column for date and time respectively in my database. Now I am creating a form which the user will select the date and time using jqueryPicker and the output format that will be in the text input space is 2013/12/29 12:52. Now, when I used a submit button I would like to store this info in the two column respectively. however, when I use $id = pg_escape_string($_POST['ID']); at the submit page, I can only input the date, how should I code it so that I can input the time to its column.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the text which you got from the DatePicker.

```
$valuefromdatepicker='2013/12/29 12:52';
$datetimeval= explode(' ',$valuefromdatepicker);
$date = $datetimeval[0]; // holds 2013/12/29
$time = $datetimeval[1]; // holds 12:52
```

Comment: the value from datepicker I have to type in? and because I using a submit button so I have to get those values at another php page, this code is for on the same page ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$DateTime= '2013-01-22 10:45:45';

echo $time = date("H:i:s",strtotime($DateTime));
echo $date= date("Y:m:d",strtotime($DateTime));
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting date

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2013/12/29 12:52'));
```

and for time.

```
echo date('H:i',strtotime('2013/12/29 12:52'));
```

See [Dateformats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) and date [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I'm not sure if the issue is:

- You have a date column in your database but when you try to insert the value with a combined date and time, only the date is being stored in the database but the time is lost
- You have a date column and a time column and you are trying to split the input string to isolate the time value to save to the time column.

In either case, I suspect the issue is not actually related to string parsing or splitting, but with your database setup. Let's go over both scenarios above:

- You insert a datetime string like `2013/12/29 12:52` and only the date is being stored but the time is dropped. You would like both the date and time to be stored on that column.

This is likely to occur if the column is set to a data type of "date", which is intended to only store date values, not time values. PostgreSQL, like MySQL and similar database servers, allows you to pass in a full datetime value for a date column and it automatically ignores the irrelevant time part of the value. If you want the full date and time to be stored in that one column, you would need to change the column's data type from "date" to "timestamp". Looking at the Postgre documentation, this could be done with an [`ALTER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html) statement similar to:

```
ALTER TABLE foo
    ALTER COLUMN foo_timestamp SET DATA TYPE timestamp;
```

- You want to store the date value in one column and the time value in another column, but aren't sure how to separate the time value for the insert.

Just as a column of type "date" will allow a full datetime value to be passed in and silently drop the time part of the input, a column of type "time" will also allow a full datetime value to be passed in and will silently drop the date part of the input, storing only the time. This means there is no need to parse the string and split the value before the insert.

However, with either of the above solutions, the database needs to be able to interpret the full datetime string correctly to interpret what is the date and what is the time and store the values accordingly. While it may not be necessary, it's a good idea to format your datetime string using a standard format to avoid potential issues.  I would recommend using php's DateTime class to achieve this, like so:

```
// assuming that the format from picker is always : 2013/05/01 01:05

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i', $_POST['datetime']);

$iso_date = $date->format(ISO8601); // returns '2013-05-01T01:05:00'
```

With the ISO-8601 formatted datetime, you can pass this in for both the date column and time column if they are separate columns or into the single timestamp column if you want to store them together.

You could also get the date and time strings as separate variables using the DateTime class as well, like so:

```
// assuming that the format from picker is always : 2013/05/01 01:05

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i', $_POST['datetime']);

$date_string = $date->format('Y-m-d'); // returns '2013-05-01';
$time_string = $date->format('H:i'); // returns '01:05';
```

Comment: i do add some comments in my question, could you be kind enough to help me look at it..thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try This: https://eval.in/83925

```
$str= "2013/12/29 12:52";
$data = explode(" ",$str);
echo "Date: ". $data[0]."   ";
echo "Time: ". $data[1];
```